# What id does getActionBar().setTitle() look for?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I've implemented a custom ActionBar layout. I'm hoping that assigning an ID to my custom layout's `TextView` that is the same as the ID in the `TextView` in the *default* ActionBar layout will let me use `getActionBar().setTitle()` with minimal fuss (no extending a custom ActionBar class, etc...).

Where can I find that ID? I looked in the `layout` files in SDK 19 and found an ID of `action_bar_title` in `action_bar_title_item.xml`, but setTitle() didn't work after assigning that id to my custom layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where can I find that ID?

`action_bar_title` is the ID you're looking for.

> setTitle() didn't work after assigning that id to my custom layout

Adding the same id to the `TextView` didn't work like you expect because the system uses its own resources. In other words `android.R.id.action_bar_title` is a different ID than `your_package_name.R.id.action_bar_title`.

But as far as easily setting the title, what's three-ish more lines?

```
private TextView mYourCustomTitle;

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    View yourCustomActionBar = ...
    mYourCustomTitle = yourCustomActionBar .findViewById(R.id.action_bar_title;

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setCustomView(yourCustomActionBar);
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    super.setTitle(title);
    mYourCustomTitle.setText(title);
}
```

Comment: Oh duh, why didn't I realize that earlier? And I didn't think to override `setTitle()`, thanks for pointing that out.